# RESTful endpoints for returning same model based on different fields?

Tags: api, rest, url, endpoint, restful-url

What is the recommended convention to be followed for identifying different GET endpoints that fetch the same model/entity using different fields/parameters?

For example, there is a `Student` entity for which I wish to expose different GET endpoints. Suppose the first GET endpoint is a get-by-id endpoint that fetches `Student` based on the provided ID. Another endpoint might involve fetching `Student` based on, say, `email`, yet another endpoint could be for fetching `Student` by `phone`.

I have a couple of possible approaches for designing their endpoints

1. Use separate endpoints `/students/get-by-id/{id}`, `/students/get-by-email/{email}` and `/students/get-by-phone/{phone}`
2. Use a single endpoint `/students` and accept request parameters like `/students?phone=123` and then in the backend resolve which method must be used for fetching.

What is the recommended method for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest option 2 because it is better to keep rest endpoint clean and simple and hide complexity inside code. Plus you wouldn't know what other requirements will arise in future like having new query field added which requires a new rest path. IMHO changing rest endpoint is similar to changing an interface which is a contract between producer and consumer.